# ActiveMQ Artemis Producer performance issue with 30k address/queues

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have an application that needs to send messages to ~30k address. I used to have OpenMQ as my broker and use JMS. The JMS client code that I have was capable of sending ~30k messages to the broker within few seconds. Then I switched to Artemis and the send performance degraded drastically. Now it takes up to 10 minutes to send all the messages to Artemis broker.

I played with different configuration settings both on the server (broker.xml) and also via connection URL.

#### Address setting on broker.xml

```xml
<address-setting match="#">
   <!-- <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address> -->
   <!-- <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address> -->
   <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
   <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
   <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
   <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
   <address-full-policy>DROP</address-full-policy>
   <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
   <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
   <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
   <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
</address-setting>
```

#### Sending

```java
private static final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616?minLargeMessageSize=10485760;compressLargeMessages=true;producerWindowSize=-1";

ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(BROKER_URL);
factory.setDupsOKBatchSize(50 * 1024 * 1024);
factory.setProducerWindowSize(-1);
factory.setBlockOnDurableSend(false);
factory.setBlockOnNonDurableSend(false);
factory.setCacheDestinations(true);
System.out.println("Connection factory " + factory.toString());

Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
Session producerSession = connection.createSession(false, ActiveMQJMSConstants.PRE_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MessageProducer producer = producerSession.createProducer(null);
producer.setDisableMessageID(true);
producer.setDisableMessageTimestamp(true);

// Create a JMS message of type ByteMessage, and send

producer.send(destination, jmsMessage, DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT, JMS_MESSAGE_PRIORITY, DEFAULT_TTL);
```

With above code (simplified for readability) I only get 20 to 40 messages per second.

Am I missing something? Or is it some performance penalty introduced by JMS to Core conversion from Artemis client library?

Is there anything I can do to improve the message rate?

Comment: Are you running this code for every message you send? How large are the messages you send? Do they exceed the `minLargeMessageSize` you've set? How many messages do you send to each destination? Are all the addresses and queues being auto created on the broker or have you pre-created them in the `broker.xml`?

Comment: For what it's worth, the JMS API is just a facade on the core client implementation. It should introduce minimal overhead and would not account for any statistically significant performance reduction.

Comment: Thanks Justin for explanation about the JMS API. To answer your questions, 1. I'm running `producer.send(..)` inside a loop. 2. Messages are small less than 1kb. 3. No, they do not exceed the `minLargeMessageSize`. 4. One message per destination in single loop iteration. I ran the loop 5 times to get the average msg/sec, so 5 messages per destination. 5. Yes, address and queues are auto created.

Comment: @JustinBertram I did little bit more digging. It seems like creating a queue for an address takes about 20 to 30 milliseconds. Does that sounds correct? That might explain ~40 msg/s.

Comment: There certainly is some overhead when an address and queue are auto-created. The client must query the broker to see if the resources exist and if they don't then it will ask the broker to create them. The broker must then create the resources and write some records to disk to make sure the resources aren't lost if a crash occurs. To eliminate this overhead, even just for testing purposes, I recommend you pre-create the addresses and queues in `broker.xml` and then run your test again.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, in general, Artemis is optimized for concurrency. Therefore, performance scales well with multiple clients working in parallel. You might try spawning multiple threads to do this production work rather that just running all of it in a single thread.

Comment: @JustinBertram Thank you for the suggestions. In our production environment those address need to be auto created, so pre-creating them in the `broker.xml` is really not an option for us. In fact I have multiple threads sending messages to the broker. I'll try increasing the number of threads even further. Do you recommend to have unique session per thread or does it even matter w.r.t. performance?

Comment: I understand you may still need auto-creation in production. My suggestion was simply to provide you with a comparison so you could quantify the overhead for auto-creation. For what it's worth, if you're sending just one message to each of the 30k destinations that's going to be the worst possible performance penalty for auto-creation. JMS sessions are not thread-safe so it's generally best to have a session per thread otherwise you have to implement some kind of locking semantics to protect the session from concurrent access.

Comment: @JustinBertram Thanks! I'll continue to tweak my test code and update this post!

Comment: Any conclusions?

Comment: @JustinBertram I'm still testing. I was able to create a core producer (without JMS) and send messages to the broker incredibly faster rates. So the producer is using core and consumers using JMS. Do you see any potential issue with that approach? Also when I send messages using core, I don't check to see if there are queues associated with the address that I sent to. Basically, I created a `ClientProducer` without a default address and do `producer.send(addressName, message)`. Also I have a question about DeliveringMessageCount on a given queue, should I create a separate questions for that?

Comment: The core protocol is a lower level protocol than JMS. It doesn't support auto-creation for addresses and queues so you will need to use the API to create them as needed. If you aren't doing that it likely explains why the sending goes so much faster because the broker isn't actually doing anything with the messages.

Comment: Yes, create a separate question about DeliveringMessageCount.